# How to declare assets?

Tags: angular, angular-cli

In the angular-cli.json file, there is the apps/assets key which lets me put assets to use.

I can declare all images I put in there and I'm able to use it afterwards. But that's clearly not the way to do it, right?

"Wtf does this fellow coding being mean?", is you right now I assume, so here is my problem in detail:

**.angular-cli.json:**

```
"apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.png"
      ],
      // Other things that do not matter
  ],
```

Somewhere in the code:

`<img src="assets/images/mycoolimage.png" alt="Johannes banannes">`

The assets folder (including the image):

```
src/assets/images/mycoolimage.png
```

I get a 404 saying the image is not found. Looking at `angular-cli.json`, there is the `assets` folder declared in it. Shouldn't this mean, that all assets should be included? The `favicon.png` for example is accessable using something like the following anywhere in the code:

`<img src="favicon.png">`

If "assets" is declared in the `assets` section (angular-cli.json), shouldn't its content be available everywhere using something like the following:

`<img src="assets/images/mycoolimage.png">`

Any help is highly appreciated.

**EDIT:** Here is a screenshot showing my folder structure:

[image: Screen]

Comment: You should be able to get the images this way. The favicon is a special case because it is compiled to the root directory of the output folder, i.e /dist/favicon.ico. Are you getting the 404s when doing an `ng serve`, or when compiling and then serving with something like `lite-server`? What's your `base_href` set to?

Comment: Use the relative path of the image

Comment: E.g. if your component.htm is under src/app/ folder, then set the image in component as <img src="../assets/images/mycoolimage.png" alt="Johannes banannes"> ... angular-cli will take care of the paths after build.

Comment: did you try using `./` at front?

Comment: @joh04667 I tried all tips here. I edited the question, maybe you can take a look. It doesn't work with `ng serve`. I didn't even try a deployment or anything, but I also don't know how to use images in an angular project tbh.

Comment: @joh04667 I found a workaround (not sure if this is the way to do it), but in the `angular-cli.json` I added under `apps -> assets` the line `assets/images`. This now gives me access to the images within that folder. I thought, when `assets` is there, all subfiles and folders would be included, but that doesn't seem the case.

Answer (score 0):

**If this is not the way to go, feel free to add an answer. I will accept it if your solution is a better way than mine.**

In the `.angular-cli.json`, I added the following line:

```
"apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "assets/images", //<<<--- This line
        "favicon.png"
      ],
      // Other things that do not matter
  ],
```

It gave me access to the images. Having only "assets" declared didn't work. It looks like angular is only including sub-files, but not sub-folders.